# Passing texture to shader in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, shader

I'm working on some examples, and I was trying to pass a texture to a shader.

To build a VAO, I have this piece of code:

```
void PlaneShaderProgram::BuildVAO()
{
    // Generate and bind the vertex array object
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vao);
    glBindVertexArray(_vao);

    // Generate and bind the vertex buffer object
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 12 * sizeof(GLfloat), _coordinates, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Generate and bind the index buffer object
    glGenBuffers(1, &_ibo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(GLuint), _indexes, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Generate and bind texture
    _texture = LoadTexture("floor.bmp");

    LoadAttributeVariables();

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

This is how I load the shader attributes:

```
void PlaneShaderProgram::LoadAttributeVariables()
{
    GLuint VertexPosition_location = glGetAttribLocation(GetProgramID(), "vPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VertexPosition_location);

    glVertexAttribPointer(VertexPosition_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
}

void PlaneShaderProgram::LoadUniformVariables()
{
    // OpenGL Matrices
    GLuint ModelViewProjection_location = glGetUniformLocation(GetProgramID(), "mvpMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelViewProjection_location, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(_ModelViewProjection));

    // Floor texture
    // glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    // glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture);
    // GLint Texture_location = glGetUniformLocation(GetProgramID(), "texture");
    // glUniform1i(Texture_location, 0);
}
```

And my `LoatTexture`:

```
GLuint ProgramManager::LoadTexture(const char* imagepath)
{
    unsigned char * data = LoadBMP(imagepath, &width, &height);

    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    return textureID;
}
```

Finally, my draw function, which is called in the OpenGL main loop, is the following:

```
void PlaneShaderProgram::DrawPlane(const glm::mat4 &Projection, const glm::mat4 &ModelView)
{
    _ModelViewProjection = Projection * ModelView;
    _ModelView = ModelView;

    Bind();

    glBindVertexArray(_vao);
    LoadUniformVariables();
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    UnBind();
}
```

What I didn't get is that even if I didn't set the uniform texture (commented in the code) used by my shader, the plane is still draw using the texture. This makes no sense for me. Once the shader requires a sample2D, I think this shouldn't work and return some error.

Vertex Shader:

```
uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;
in vec4 vPosition;

smooth out vec2 uvCoord;

void main() 
{
   uvCoord = vPosition.xz;
   gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vPosition;
}
```

Frag Shader:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
in vec2 uvCoord;

out vec4 fragColor;
void main()
{ 
    fragColor.rgb = texture(texture, uvCoord).rgb;
};
```

Am I missing something? Somehow this works I don't understand why, but I really like to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sampler` data types in GLSL reference the texture *unit*, not a texture *object*. By default, uniforms will be initialized to 0, so if you don't set the `sampler` uniforms, they will sample from texture unit 0 (which is also the default unit). In your `ProgramManager::LoadTexture()` method, you bind the newly created texture, and very likely you are still using `GL_TEXTURE0` as the currently active texture unit. You never seem to unbind it, so it is still bound at the time of the draw call, and the shader can access it.

Comment: Thank you, @derhass. Completely understood now. :)